# Permutations in python without libraries

Tags: python

I am trying to produce a function that should takes as input a range, and for that range should be return all the possible permutation of that range without use any library.

for example:

```
per(range(3))
```

should return:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
```

I have done the following but i get an empty list.

```
def per(l):
    return [l[i]+p for i in range(len(l))for p in per(l[:i] + l [i+1:])]
```

Does anyone know why i get the empty list and how to solve it?

Comment: Sounds like it might be homework, in which case you might be satisfied with a simple recursive solution. But -- if you are going to *do* anything with these permutations then you might want to look into the Johnson-Trotter algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the end condition for you would be when the length of list `l` is `0` and that returns an empty list back. Hence when length of list is `1`, the inner loop never actually runs and hence this also returns an empty list back , and this keeps on happenning and you always get empty lists.

An fix would be to make the end condition when the length of list is `1`, and you should return lists of lists, not simple lists. Example -

```
def per(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return [l]
    return [[l[i]] + p for i in range(len(l))for p in per(l[:i] + l [i+1:])]
```

Demo -

```
>>> def per(l):
...     if len(l) == 1:
...         return [l]
...     return [[l[i]] + p for i in range(len(l))for p in per(l[:i] + l [i+1:])]
...
>>>
>>> per([2])
[[2]]
>>> per([0,1,2])
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]]
>>> per([0,1,2, 3])
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 3, 2], [0, 2, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 3, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 3, 2], [1, 2, 0, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 3, 0, 2], [1, 3, 2, 0], [2, 0, 1, 3], [2, 0, 3, 1], [2, 1, 0, 3], [2, 1, 3, 0], [2, 3, 0, 1], [2, 3, 1, 0], [3, 0, 1, 2], [3, 0, 2, 1], [3, 1, 0, 2], [3, 1, 2, 0], [3, 2, 0, 1], [3, 2, 1, 0]]
>>> len(per([0,1,2, 3]))
24
```

Comment: This would also work with the the end condition for recursion being when length of list is `0` , but for that you would need to return a empty list of lists, example - `[[]]` .

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you for your help! :)